# Having minimize issues running games in wine with gnome shel

Tags: 12.04, gnome, 64-bit, wine, ati

Ok, I have 4 computers all running Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome Shell. on all computers when ever I play games in wine I set wine to run in a virtual desktop. On the first 3 computers I can use things like "Alt-Tab" and I can use the "Super/Windows" key to get into overview mode while playing games and it functions absolutely flawless, I can even move the game to another deaktop and continue playing. However on the 4th Computer neither "Alt-Tab" or "Super" Do anything, as a matter of fact if I hit them more than once the window will loose focus and I have to shutdown to get out of the game. I also noticed on the 4th computer that the Volume popup for Gnome Shell doesnt diplay either, but it does on the other 3.

All 4 Computers are running Ubuntu 12.04 (fully up-to-date), and they are all running Gnome Shell (Fully up-to-date from the offical Gnome 3 PPA). All Computers have thier respective proriatary graphics drivers installed.

`1st: Works Fine
AMD CPU and
AMD Radeon HD6850 Graphics`

`2nd: Works Fine
AMD CPU (mobile) and
AMD Radeon HD 6520G graphics`

`3rd: Works Fine (Only PC running 32bit Ubuntu)
AMD CPU and
Nvidia GeForce GTS 250 graphics`

`4th: Doesnt Work
AMD CPU and
ATI Radeon HD4850 graphics`

EDIT: A friend of mine is also running 12.04 64bit with Gnome shell and a Radeon HD 4850, he is also not able to do this either. Could it be something specific to the HD4850? I can do it just fine on my HD 6850.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most games running on wine, alt tab start working only when you set (in 'winecfg') compatibilty to windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I switched it over to Windows 7 and it still does not work. However it did help with it loosing focus. I'm updating my original post with some new info I found.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, switching out of fullscreen 3D applications (games) works flawless with the open source radeon drivers but does not work at all with the proprietary ATI/AMD fglrx drivers.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was enable virtual desktop in wine config using the resolution of my pc, for example in my notebook I set the resolution to 1366x768 and used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back to game. I must press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, if I don't the letters won't work correctly.